# Data.List.Ordered.unionAllBy comparing infinite lists

Tags: haskell

So I have as inputs 2 sorted lists, that can be infinite. 
I have to write a function prod, that returns basically a product of cartesian product coordinates in sorted order.

Example:

```
prod [2,4,5,10] [2,3] -> [4,6,8,10,12,15,20,30]
```

For finite lists, it is as easy as

```
import Data.List
prod xs ys = sort [x*y | x<-xs, y<-ys]
```

But problem is when I try to use it with infinite lists. I was thinking that because inputs are sorted, I can use `Data.List.Ordered.unionAllBy`, but I can't understand how to use it. The comparing option confuses me.

So I Could use a function I wrote:

```
sequence2 xs ys = [[i*j| i<-xs]|j<-ys]
```

Example:

```
sequence2 [2,4,5] [3,4,5] -> [[6,12,15],[8,16,20],[10,20,25]]
```

I imagine my solution would look something like:

```
Data.List.Ordered.unionAllBy (comparison) (sequence' xs ys)
```

Any hints how I can modify this to use infinite lists as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison passed to `unionAllBy` is a function with the same type and following the same rules as the `compare` function from an [`Ord`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord) instance. If you have an `Ord` instance you can use [`unionAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:unionAll) instead of `unionAllBy`.

```
unionAllBy ::          (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [[a]] -> [a]
unionAll   :: Ord a =>                         [[a]] -> [a]
compare    :: Ord a =>  a -> a -> Ordering

unionAll = unionAllBy compare
```

A comparison function takes two objects and says what order they are in: `LT`, `EQ`, or `GT`. The best explanation of what `compare` should do is probably the default definition for it in the [`Ord` class in the standard prelude](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#verbatim-167)

> ```
> compare x y  
>      | x == y    =  EQ  
>      | x <= y    =  LT  
>      | otherwise =  GT  
>
> x <= y           =  compare x y /= GT  
> x <  y           =  compare x y == LT  
> x >= y           =  compare x y /= LT  
> x >  y           =  compare x y == GT
> ```

The `unionAll` function will make a union of your `sequence2` lists in order removing duplicates from between lists. `unionAll` doesn't remove duplicates present in a single input list.

```
> unionAll $ sequence2 [2,4,5] [3,4,5]
[6,8,10,12,15,16,20,25]
                 ^
                 only one twenty
```

It will also flatten `sequence2` applied to infinite lists in order

```
> take 12 . unionAll $ sequence2 [2,4..] [3,5..]
[6,10,12,14,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,34]
```

If you want to keep duplicates, use [`mergeAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:mergeAll) instead.

```
> mergeAll $ sequence2 [2,4,5] [3,4,5]
[6,8,10,12,15,16,20,20,25]
                 ^  ^
                 two twenties
```

Comment: This works. But one question - why is there 8 elements instead of 9 ? 
The result should be something like 
[6,8,10,12,15,16,20,20,25]. From what I read in documentation, it should allow duplicates also, same thing with [2,2,2] [4,4,4] results in [8,8,8] and not [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8]. This seems strange to me.

Comment: From the `unionAll` documentation: "The result will duplicate an element as many times as the maximum number of occurrences in any single list. Thus, the result is a set if and only if every inner list is a set"

Comment: @La'tel `unionAll` only keeps duplicates *within* each list. If you want to keep *all* duplicates, use `mergeAll` instead.